# Use clang with OpenMPI

Tags: clang, openmpi

I'm trying to use clang with OpenMPI. I have set the wrapper compiler using

```
export OMPI_CC=clang
```

When I try to verify the compiler mpicc is invoking by using

```
mpicc --showme:command
```

I get this error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, a sample mpi code runs fine using regular mpicc and mpirun commands, I guess its sticking back to the default mpicc compiler and not clang. I need to use certain clang functionalities for the OpenMPI code. How do I rectify this error.

Comment: Does openmpi build under clang?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing this problem on Linux Mint 17.3 with clang-3.8 and OpenMPI-1.6.5 (Debian package). Maybe it's an issue with the Red Hat package?